# Is there anyway to bypass "region/language select" when web scraping?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm using the requests library in python and I'm trying to make a get request for the content of a web page, however, the first thing that shows up is a popup requesting for the region and language. Is there anything I can supply to the header to bypass this? The website is www.stockx.com

Comment: Hello. Your question seems to relate to a specific website issue rather than a generic Python web scraping question. However, i can speculate that the website wants you to issue a request, get a cooke and keep that cookie.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work